Finding dual of a linear programming problem max $c^{T}X$ such that $Ax \geq b$ and $x \leq 0$
I don't know much about duality theory. I just saw from Wikipedia that if we consider the following linear programming:
$max ~c^{T}x
\\ Ax \leq b
\\ x \geq 0$
Dual of this problem will be
$min ~b^{T}y
\\ A^{T}y \geq c
\\ y \geq 0$
Is it always necessary that $x \geq 0$?
Or, we can find the dual of the following problem:
$max ~c^{T}x
\\ Ax \geq b
\\ x \leq 0$
If we assume $y = -x$, then $y \geq 0$. Is it the correct way to think?

The direction of the constraints in the dual depends on the sign of the variable in the primal.
If the primal is the  maximization problem,
$$\max c^Tx$$
$$Ax \ge b$$
$$x \le 0$$
then the corresponding dual is the minimization problem
$$\min b^Ty$$
$$A^Ty \le c$$
$$y \le 0$$
Here is a  table that can help you write down the dual obtained from here.


Thanks for your answer.
